# Dependency Injection of Sub-Class with providedIn: root

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

When I have:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyServiceBase {
  ...
}
```

and

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyService extends MyServiceBase {
  ...
}
```

then I get an instance of the **base class**. Here's some proof: https://stackblitz.com/edit/subclass-dependency-injection

**How can I tell the DI to use subclass and no the base class?** I would have thought Angular is smart enough to detect that I want MyService and not MyServiceBase...?

Also, I don't want to make MyServiceBase abstract, as I'm directly using it in one project, but I use the subclassed version in another project.

Comment: You could make the base service not injectable, and defined two injectable derived classes, one of them being just `export class MySimpleService extends MyServiceBase { }` (without any additional code). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/subclass-dependency-injection-2zrfwy).